# Working with Batch File

Tags: windows, reboot, events, viewer

I'm in need a bat file to clear Event Viewer logs and re-boot computer...or help in modifying the ones I already have so that once ran from an administrator prompt, it'd clear the logs...and reboot the computer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the
[wevtutil commnad](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil)
in your batch script.

To clear a specific log, you must first know its name.
To see a list of Event Logs, run:

```
wevtutil el > Loglist.txt
```

Find the name of the log you want to clear and use it on the command.

For example, to clear the Application log, use the following command:

```
wevtutil cl Application
```

---

To reboot, use the
[shutdown command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown):

```
shutdown -r
```

This requires administrator permissions.

Comment: Appreciate the input, I already have three scripts that do these individually.

Answer (score 0):

The following script searches for *all* Event logs, clears them, then reboots on success. It must be run as Admin.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO SET adminTest=%%V
IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto noAdmin
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%%G")
rem Event Logs have been cleared!
shutdown -r
goto fini
:do_clear
echo clearing %1
wevtutil.exe cl %1
goto :eof
:noAdmin
echo You must run this script as an Administrator!
pause
echo.
:fini
```

Comment: The script for clearing ALL Event logs and rebooting works for my need, thanks. I did notice that b4 rebooting, there is a notification much like when one receives a remote shutdown from a network computer. That is due to the 'shutdown -r' instruction, correct?

Comment: There is also a delay of about 45 secs to a minute before the computer actually reboots. Is there a way to reboot, immediately without waiting to allotted 45 secs to a minute?

Comment: Or to cut the wait time to a 20 sec delay? I ask because when I send remote shutdowns using a third party program to any one of me 7 rigs on my home network, there is an option to delay or speedup sent instructions by xx -xx seconds. For curiosity sake only, the script supplied works good as is, indeed.

Comment: **shutdown /r /t 0** reboots with no delay, **shutdown /s /t 0** shuts down with no delay. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown for **shutdown** command-line options. Noe that in most versions of Windows, hyphen may be used instead of forward-slash.